# Python Import Error - specific case

Tags: python, importerror

I know there has been a ton of questions about this, but mine is pretty specific and i don't really know why the import is not working. 
I've got the following Folder Structure:

```
importmodule
-classes
-pluginhelper
-- __init__.py

-plugins
-- plugin_a
-- plugin b
-- ..

-__init__.py
-<other py files>
```

In my plugin files i am importing the pluginhelper like this:

```
from importmodule.pluginhelper import function1, function2, ...
```

The functions are defined in the __ init __.py

Executing my plugin files works great on my windows machine. When i do it on the server, i get following Exception:

```
 ImportError: No module named 'importmodule'
```

The curious thing is, that i do get the error from every plugin, but one. In one of the plugins the import works, while there is no difference in the import statements.

I am using python 3.5 on both machines, while on the server my application is within a docker container.

Edit: 
Setting the sys.path didnt work either :

```
  print("Indexed Path for Package.")
  sys.path.index(os.getcwd())
```

I found the possible problem: 
**The folder structure in my dockercontainer seems to be different. I will fix it and tell you if it helped.** Still i don't understand why it works with the one plugin using the same statement.

Comment: Have you tried `from pluginhelper import function1, function2, ...`?

Comment: PyCharm is highlighting me this one instantly, since it seems to be searching in importmodule.plugins.plugina.plugina.pluginhelper

Comment: I see, then try adding `__init__.py` in your `plugins` folder to make Python treat it as a module.

Comment: Still couldnt import pluginhelper like you suggested. I am wondering why it is working with one plugin.

Comment: Keep the import like originally :D

Comment: `from importmodule.pluginhelper import function1, function2, ...`

Comment: Yeah, but the original version doesnt work on the server somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to share my solution with you, since anybody reading the question seems to have similar problems.

The problem occured because the package werent included in pythonpath / syspath. I am calling the plugins in a new thread with a script called execute.py. This is called via cmd from the main.py because i can't multiprocess my classes. And since the plugins are located in ../plugins, python only includes this path. Not the /importmodule path. Somehow it seems that it has been included on windows, i dont really know what has happened there tbh.

What i did was, i included the `sys.path.append` stuff on my execute.py which executes the plugins as follows: `from pluginhelper import scrapeHostnames, hostnamesToIps, getSource`. My IDE marks the import statement red now, but it is working, since i am appending the package.